# Is it possible to import/migrate functionality/specific files from one Amazon Connect instance to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, code-migration

Is it possible to import/migrate functionality/specific files from one Amazon Connect instance to another?

We've built out call center functionality within one Amazon Connect instance but we'd like to migrate the code/files over to another instance so we can leverage the functionality that we've already built.

Comment: When you say "AWS instance", are you referring to an "Amazon Connect instance" or "Amazon EC2 instance"? I don't think you can put code/files on an Amazon Connect instance -- it is just a virtual call center configuration. Can you please edit your question to provide more information?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is an Amazon Connect Instance. We want to take the configurations and code that we wrote from one instance to another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to copy an Amazon Connect instance to another one.

You will need to recreate the resources manually.

Comment: Hi John - thanks for responding. How would one manually copy the code/configurations to another instance?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording. You will need to create each element by hand in the new instance. There is no 'copy' function.